# Modelling projectile with lift and drag forces

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, physics

I am trying to model a projectile motion with lift and drag forces.
I have written the code below, solved for $y$ and $x$, and tried to plot it.

However, I don't know how to implement the fact that the lift and drag force **increase quadratically** with the speed $v$. In my current code, I specified $v$ as if it is constant, which is obviously not true.

My code:

```
vinitial := QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[60, "Meters"/"Seconds"]]
vinitialx := Cos[θ]*vinitial
vinitialy := Sin[θ]*vinitial
Fdrag := -(1/2*ρ*A*Cdrag)*Abs[vinitial]*vinitial
Flift := (1/2*ρ*A*CL)*Abs[vinitial]*vinitial
Fweight := -m*g
Clear[Fdrag, Flift, Fweight]
```

```
(*Setting up the two master equations for x and y*)
eq1 := m*y \.08'' == -m*g + (1/2*ρ*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v
eq2 := m*x'' ==  -(1/2*ρ*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v
Clear[eq1, eq2]
```

```
ρ := 1.204
A := Pi*2^2
m := 0.05
CL := 0.3
Cdrag := 0.3
g := 9.81
```

```
DSolve[{y''[t] == -g + (1/2*ρ*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*cos[θ] - 
    1/m (1/2*ρ*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*sin[θ], 
  y'[0] == vinitialy, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
DSolve[{x''[t] == -1/m*(1/2*ρ*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*cos[θ] - 
    1/m (1/2*ρ*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*sin[θ], x'[0] == vinitialx, 
  x[0] == 0}, x[t], t]
DSolve[{x'[t] == -1/m*(1/2*ρ*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*t, 
  x'[0] == vinitialx}, x'[t], t]
```

```
yfunction[t_] = 
 y[t] /. First[
   DSolve[{y''[
       t] == -g + (1/m)*(1/2*ρ*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*
        Cos[θ] - (1/m)*(1/2*ρ*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*
        Sin[θ], y'[0] == vinitialy, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]]
```

```
xfunction[t_] = 
 x[t] /. First[
   DSolve[{x''[
       t] == -1/m*(1/2*ρ*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*Cos[θ] - 
       1/m*(1/2*ρ*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*Sin[θ], 
     x'[0] == vinitialx, x[0] == 0}, x[t], t]]
```

```
v = 2
θ = Pi/3
ParametricPlot[{xfunction[t], yfunction[t]}, {t, 0, 15}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-40, 40}, {0, 40}}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! There are several things I would like to point out. First, do not use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) for your constants, just use normal `Set`, ie. `ρ = 1.204`. Second, you first define your equations multiple times, then don't use them when you acually solve them in `DSolve` – please clean your code so that it only contains what is necessary for it to work. Third, to properly include drag and lift, you should use the current velocity, which can be calculated as `Norm[{x'[t], y'[t]}]^2`. If it is easier for you, you can also define an auxilliary quantity, the angle

Comment: ... `θ[t] == ArcTan[x'[t], y'[t]]` and include this into the set of differential equations. Fourth, by including lift and drag, the $x$ and $y$ components are now _coupled_. This means you cannot solve them separately as you do, but you have to solve them together, with one `DSolve` that has all the DE equations in it. Lastly, I doubt you need an exact solution, so use `NDSolve` for numeric solver instead of `DSolve`. I suggest you try implementing my suggestions, then edit the question if you still encounter problems :)

Comment: Thanks, I will implement this, the reason I used DSolve instead of NDsolve is that I need to make graphs for multiple angles to see what the effect is of the angle on the horizontal distance travelled.

Comment: If I define velocity as ``` Norm[x'[t]^2 + y't^2] I get an recursion error.

Comment: @Consider `ParametricNDSolve` then and set the angle as a parameter. You will then get a numerical solver object in which you can substitute different values of the angle.

Comment: I tried to use NDSolve but I get an error that the arguments are not arranged properly, I dont know if this works:

Comment: ```
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -g + (1/2*\[Rho]*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*cos[\[Theta]] - 
    1/m (1/2*\[Rho]*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*sin[\[Theta]], 
  x''[t] == -1/m*(1/2*\[Rho]*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*cos[\[Theta]] - 
    1/m (1/2*\[Rho]*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*sin[\[Theta]], y'[0] == vinitialy, 
  x'[0] == vinitialx, y[0] == 0,  x[0] == 0}, x[t], y[t], t]

Comment: @dutchrunner, please pay attention to my (2)nd point and edit your question accordingly. Then we can proceed with discussing your code :)

Comment: I tried ParametricNDsolve,

Comment: is this correct? 
`
ParametricNDSolve[{y''[
    t] == -g + (1/2*\[Rho]*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*cos[\[Theta]] - 
    1/m (1/2*\[Rho]*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*sin[\[Theta]], 
  x''[t] == -1/m*(1/2*\[Rho]*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*cos[\[Theta]] - 
    1/m (1/2*\[Rho]*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*sin[\[Theta]], y'[0] == vinitialy, 
  x'[0] == vinitialx, y[0] == 0,  x[0] == 0}, x[t], y[t], \[Theta]]  

`

Comment: `ParametricNDSolve[{y''[
    t] == -g + (1/2*\[Rho]*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*cos[\[Theta]] - 
    1/m (1/2*\[Rho]*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*sin[\[Theta]], 
  x''[t] == -1/m*(1/2*\[Rho]*A*Cdrag)*Abs[v]*v*cos[\[Theta]] - 
    1/m (1/2*\[Rho]*A*CL)*Abs[v]*v*sin[\[Theta]], y'[0] == vinitialy, 
  x'[0] == vinitialx, y[0] == 0,  x[0] == 0}, x[t], y[t], \[Theta]]`  
`y[t_] := -4.905` t^2 + 
  22.694865329532664` t^2 v Abs[v] Cos[\[Theta]] + 
  60 t Sin[\[Theta]] - 22.694865329532664` t^2 v Abs[v] Sin[\[Theta]]`

Comment: `x[t_] := 
 60 t Cos[\[Theta]] - 
  22.694865329532664` t^2 v Abs[v] Cos[\[Theta]] - 
  22.694865329532664` t^2 v Abs[v] Sin[\[Theta]]`

`v = Norm[{y'[t], x'[t]}]^2`

`\[Theta] = Pi/6`
`ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]`
I get no plot right now

Comment: @MarcoB I tried to use the parameter theta, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: The thing is, I would like to make a graph of the y and x position to find a sort of parabola, If i have theta as parameter, I cant change t and cant make a graph,

Comment: This is what I have so far 
```y[t]=-4.905 t^2 + 22.6949 t^2 v Abs[v] Cos[\[Theta]] + 
 60 t Sin[\[Theta]] - 22.6949 t^2 v Abs[v] Sin[\[Theta]]```
```x[t]=60 t Cos[\[Theta]] - 22.6949 t^2 v Abs[v] Cos[\[Theta]] - 
 22.6949 t^2 v Abs[v] Sin[\[Theta]]```  Now I would need a way to define v witout getting a recursion error, I know v is related to x'[t] and y'[t] but both expressions have a v^2 in it, so I dont know how to implement this into these two equations, I would like to graph the trajectory for different ```theta``` but dont know how.